# Autenticar Requisição AJAX - PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Utilizando como exemplo a requisição abaixo e usando como parâmetro o `id`, tenho o retorno conforme esperado

**Ajax**

```
let id = 1;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url : 'controller/get_objeto/' + id,
    success: (function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }),
    ....
```

**PHP**

```
// controller
public function get_objeto($id)
{
    if ($id== 0)
    {           
        $dados = $this->aviso->get();
    }
    else
    {
        $dados = $this->aviso->get_by_id($id);
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($dados);
}
```

**Retorno**

```
{"id":1,"tipo":"1","titulo":"teste","descricao":"teste"}
```

Se eu copiar a requisição realizada no console XRH do navegador, consigo fazer a requisição diretamente na barra de endereço URL do navegador, alterando o parâmetro `id`, bastando utilizar a URL completa.

**Exemplo**

```
http://localhost/aplicação/controller/get_objeto/1
```

Tentei utilizar desta mesma forma em outra aplicação existente, copiando a URL completa da requisição e colando na barra de endereço URL do navegador e tive o seguinte retorno:

```
{"error":"unauthorized_request","message":"Unauthorized request: no authentication given","status":401}
```

Minha pergunta é:
É possível fazer este tipo de autenticação em uma requisição AJAX e PHP, se sim, existe alguma forma simples de se fazer ?

Comment: A ferramenta do editor de amostra de código, que usa o acento grave, como o nome diz foi feito para amostras de código, não para dar ênfases em textos ou siglas. Se realmente acha que uma parte do texto precisa de ênfase, utilize o negrito. Quanto ao problema, você verificou os cabeçalhos enviados a partir da requisição AJAX? Para o servidor sempre chegará uma requisição HTTP, independente se é a partir do AJAX ou não - e nem deveria fazer diferença. Como foi bloqueado quando acessado direto pela URL, é bem provável que a autenticação é feita a partir de um cabeçalho que você não enviou.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu não enviei e nem verifiquei os cabeçalhos enviados, é por este motivo que abri a questão, para entender como é feito.

Comment: Então seria interessante colocar as requisições em questão na pergunta, caso contrário qualquer resposta será baseado em achismo podendo não representar a real situação.

Comment: O que tenho, coloquei na questão.

Comment: o `contentType: 'application/json',` você usa para retornar em formato json, é isso? Se for você pode substituir para `dataType: 'json'` e veja se dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Ai no seu php você tira header...

Comment: @adventistaam, minha questão não é sobre retornar json ou não, isso eu consigo.
Minha questão é sobre autenticar a requisição, caso passe a url diretamente pela barra de endereço..

Comment: Tente tirar o header

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, este seria um envio e verificação válido de cabeçalho http ?
`beforeSend: function(xhr){ xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Header'); },` e `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HEADER'])){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Talvez existe outra forma, mas resolvi da seguinte forma:

Na requisição ajax, enviei da seguinte forma, incluíndo o `headers: {'X-Header': ''},`:

```
let id = 1;
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
async: false,
contentType: 'application/json',
headers: {'X-Header': ''},
url : 'controller/get_objeto/' + id,
success: (function (data) {
    console.log(data)
}),
....
```

E no PHP:

```
public function get_objeto($id)
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HEADER']))
    {
        if ($id== 0)
        {
            $dados = $this->aviso->get();
        }
        else
        {
            $dados = $this->aviso->get_by_id($id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $dados = [
            'error'   => 'unauthorized_request',
            'message' => 'Unauthorized request: no authentication given',
            'status'  => 401
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: ou você pode definir um `$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-HEADER': '' } })` antes do `$.ajax`